# Shiny Datatable error - table id=DataTables_Table_1 - Ajax error

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In my Shiny App, I have a **Data.table** implemented through the package `data.table`.

My Shiny app working absolutely fine on the local Server, however when I deployed it to Digital-ocean, I frequently get error as below :

```
DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_1 - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7
```

It is not that, I get this error every time, however quite frequently, and failed to repeat my experiment to regenerate that error. Appear like, this error comes up randomly?

I searched over the Internet, however, failed to get any concrete suggestion how to circumvent this problem arising on the Shiny application.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure you used the `data.table`-package? Because suggests there is something wrong with [tag:datatables] for which the `DT`-package is an interface in R.

Comment: I used DT::renderDataTable function

Comment: This is not `datal.table`. I'm removing the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you claim you deploy the shiny app on DigitalOcean and the app works well locally, I suspect the DT version on your server is not the latest.

You can check the version of DT by adding something like `outputText("dt_version")` to ui.R and `output$dt_version <- renderText(packageVersion("DT"))` to server.R.

If not, please install the developing version of DT via `devtools::install_github('rstudio/DT')` and try again (I bet you are using shiny-server, please remember to restart the server to ensure the newly installed package being loaded).

Comment: Hi Shrek, installed version of DT is DT_0.4.9, (R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)). OS : Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS. There are various other packages loaded for my App. Not sure if DT has any confilct with any other packages - are you aware of any such?

Comment: No, I've never encountered the issue. It's difficult for me to help if there's no reproducible example and so little information. However, the ajax error means it relates to the server-processing mode, there's a chance that you may find setting the `server = FALSE` (in the `output$your_tbl_id <- DT::renderDT({...}, server = FALSE)`) helps.

Comment: I think adding server = FALSE is the key to my problem. After I added this, I dont see this problem coming back. However, given that I previously used to see this problem occurred - what I feel randomly - I am yet to assertain if this solves my problem fo good. But anyway thanks for this suggestion.